# Magento2.4.5 Console Display HTML tags must be properly nested and closed

Tags: magento2

Magento CE 2.4.5 display "HTML tags must be properly nested and closed:"
How to fixed on folllow code:
[image]

```
JQMIGRATE: HTML tags must be properly nested and closed: <div if="isPaymentMethodsAvailable()"
     class="items payment-methods">
<div repeat="foreach: paymentGroupsList, item: '$group'"
         class="payment-group">
<!-- ko if: showFormShared($group) -->
<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('billing-address-form-shared') -->
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->
<!--/ko-->
<each args="data: getRegion($group().displayArea), as: 'method'" render=""/>
</div>
</div>
<div ifnot="isPaymentMethodsAvailable()"
     class="no-payments-block"
     translate="'No Payment Methods'">
</div>
```

```
JQMIGRATE: HTML tags must be properly nested and closed: <div class="order-comment-block">
<label class="label">
<span data-bind="i18n: 'Order comment'"></span>
</label>
<div class="control">
<textarea class="admin__control-textarea" data-bind="
            value: value,
            valueUpdate: valueUpdate,
            hasFocus: focused,
            attr: {
                name: inputName,
                cols: cols,
                rows: rows,
                'aria-describedby': noticeId,
                placeholder: placeholder,
                id: uid,
                disabled: disabled
            }"
                />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. The fix for the first code:

It will be located somewhere like `app/design/frontend/YourThemeVendor/YourTheme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/payment-methods/list.html`

```
<div if="isPaymentMethodsAvailable()"
     class="items payment-methods">
     <div repeat="foreach: paymentGroupsList, item: '$group'"
              class="payment-group">
          <!-- ko if: showFormShared($group) -->
          <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('billing-address-form-shared') -->
          <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
          <!--/ko-->
          <!--/ko-->
     <each args="data: getRegion($group().displayArea), as: 'method'" render=""></each>
     </div>
</div>
<div ifnot="isPaymentMethodsAvailable()"
     class="no-payments-block"
     translate="'No Payment Methods'">
</div>
```

In the above code, I've added the close tag for `each` tag: `<each args="data: getRegion($group().displayArea), as: 'method'" render=""></each>`

2. The fix for the second code:

```
<div class="order-comment-block">
     <label class="label">
          <span data-bind="i18n: 'Order comment'"></span>
     </label>
     <div class="control">
          <textarea class="admin__control-textarea" data-bind="
                      value: value,
                      valueUpdate: valueUpdate,
                      hasFocus: focused,
                      attr: {
                          name: inputName,
                          cols: cols,
                          rows: rows,
                          'aria-describedby': noticeId,
                          placeholder: placeholder,
                          id: uid,
                          disabled: disabled
                      }"
                          ></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code is from a custom module so I don't know where it locates, you can find the path for that file by running this command: `grep -r "order-comment-block" app vendor`.
In the above code, I've added the close tag for `textarea` tag: `<textarea></textarea>`

Conclusion: Since Magento 2.4.4, you have to make sure all *.html files have the correct open/close tags. Closing tags with `/>` is not allowed anymore.

Comment: Thanks @Tu Van, This worked like a charm! 
change all />  and make it proper ending
<span /> to <span></span>
<each  ... /> to <each> </each>

Comment: @ShyamRanpara Glad to hear that. Cheers

Comment: This solution worked really well for me. Thanks @TuVan!