# Find Javascript Merge Knockout Error In Extensions Uncaught Error: Cannot find closing comment tag to match: ko template:

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs, pagespeed, merge-css

Magento 2.4.3
Apache
Nginx
MariaDB

Hello Thanks for taking the time to read this.

We have a dev site we are trying to enable Swissup Pagespeed Extension however it is getting 1 error - the merge javascript fails and different sections of the site is not working

VM26:266 Uncaught Error: Cannot find closing comment tag to match:  ko template: { name: templates.loader }

We have approx 40 Third Party Extensions from one Company and it seems there is a minor syntax error somewhere in one of the extension files -

Please can anyone advise what is the best and fastest way to isolate which extension is causing the error - in chrome console it is not showing anything - atleast I can't see any exact reference to the extension

If we disable all the extension the error does not show - but disabling them one by one is not feasible because alot of dependencies within the extensions which is causing more errors.

full error is

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find closing comment tag to match:  ko template: { name: templates.loader } 
at getVirtualChildren (eval at require.load (0e8c8f7bbcafffb3cb467ecd2c1bf316.min.js:178:216), <anonymous>:266:7)
at getMatchingEndComment (eval at require.load (0e8c8f7bbcafffb3cb467ecd2c1bf316.min.js:178:216), <anonymous>:267:85)
at Object.nextSibling (eval at require.load (0e8c8f7bbcafffb3cb467ecd2c1bf316.min.js:178:216), <anonymous>:282:186)
at applyBindingsToDescendantsInternal (eval at require.load (0e8c8f7bbcafffb3cb467ecd2c1bf316.min.js:178:216), <anonymous>:314:353)
at applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal (eval at require.load (0e8c8f7bbcafffb3cb467ecd2c1bf316.min.js:178:216), <anonymous>:320:234)
at applyBindingsToDescendantsInternal (eval at require.load (0e8c8f7bbcafffb3cb467ecd2c1bf316.min.js:178:216), <anonymous>:316:90)
at applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal (eval at require.load (0e8c8f7bbcafffb3cb467ecd2c1bf316.min.js:178:216), <anonymous>:320:234)
at applyBindingsToDescendantsInternal (eval at require.load (0e8c8f7bbcafffb3cb467ecd2c1bf316.min.js:178:216), <anonymous>:316:90)
at ko.applyBindingsToDescendants (eval at require.load (0e8c8f7bbcafffb3cb467ecd2c1bf316.min.js:178:216), <anonymous>:343:1)
at applyComponents (eval at require.load (0e8c8f7bbcafffb3cb467ecd2c1bf316.min.js:178:216), <anonymous>:3:413)e
```

If we use another pagespeed extension and use the Merge JS the error is not coming.

Comment: Thank You Tu Van very very helpful and knowledgeable kind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Debugging instructions:**
The error message indicates that the template file which contains `name: templates.loader` caused that error.
So you can find that template file by running this command:

```
grep -r "name: templates.loader" app vendor
```

**Solution:**
Your issue is related to some HTML elements does not have close tags, so you should make sure all HTML elements have close tags. Additionally, since Magento 2.4.4 HTML tags **must** be properly nested and closed.
You can take a look at a commit from Magento codebase that fixes HTML tags not properly closed to know how to implement that: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/5955a29bb38ba6dbcdae51fc2a6fc4f76be8ac57

I've also written a little about how to add close tags here: [Magento2.4.5 Console Display HTML tags must be properly nested and closed](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/361476/magento2-4-5-console-display-html-tags-must-be-properly-nested-and-closed/361478#361478)

Reference for your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727897/knockout-error-cannot-find-closing-comment-tag-to-match

Comment: thanks for reply i did see that post before but I am wanting to know if there any way of finding the file or even the extension which is causing this error

Comment: I've updated debugging instructions in my answer, please take a look.

Comment: thank you again - so I add the in 2 places the code you have kindly provided in this file /public_html/lib/web/knockoutjs and where should the element show in browser debug or another file? or inside here pub/static/frontend/YourVendor/YourTheme/en_US/knockoutjs?

Comment: you should put these code in pub/static/frontend/YourVendor/YourTheme/en_US/knockoutjs. The link from lib file in github is for reference. Then re-deploy static content, go to frontend page and check the Console tab

Comment: thank you I cant see any knockoutjs. in pub/static/frontend/YourVendor/YourTheme/en_US/knockoutjs. only knockout.min.js    knockout-es5.min.js   knockout-fast-foreach.min.js are there -

Comment: that file knockoutjs. is inside here /public_html/lib/web/knockoutjs

Comment: Oh, just realize my last comment above has a mistake, you shouldn't re-deploy static in that case because you edit the JS file directly from pub/static folder for quick testing. Now, you need to add the code I mentioned in my answer into lib/web/knockoutjs/knockout.js and then re-deploy static content (remember to remove pub/static/frontend/ var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend)

Comment: Thanks Thats how I did it what should the result of doing this be should it show in chrome elements highlighted the extension causing the error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140635/discussion-between-tu-van-and-nem3943).